# Azure App Service with OpenID authentication for backend services (WebAPI, Resource Server): Access Token issue

Tags: azure, openid-connect, easy-auth

[image]

I have two web application hosted on Azure. A front-end and a back-end. For both I configured to use EasyAuth (added a 3rd party OpenID Connect Identity Provider on the Azure Portal). When the user opens a browser, s/he navigates to the Front-end web app, which redirects the user to sign in on the identity provider login page. When the login is successful it receives an id_token (JWT format) and an access_token (**which is not in JWT format, it is just a string but according to the Oauth 2.0 specification it does not have to be in JWT**).

The user can login and access to front end app without any problem and it works as expected. Even the /.auth/me endpoint gives back the tokens and claims.

**The issue:**
When the front end calls a WebAPI endpoint  in the backend using the access token (request header Bearer ...) then the application receives the follwing error message:

> JWT: '[PII is hidden]' must have three segments (JWS) or five segments
> (JWE).

Azure seems to expect the access token in a JWT format (Azure Active Directory generates access tokens in JWT format), but as I mentioned before it is not a must. If the front end sends the id_token to the backend as the Bearer in the request header then it works, but that is strictly against the specification as ID tokens should not be used for authorization.

A workaround if I turn off the authentication for the back-end on Azure and I validate the access token on code level (using token introspection). However than what is the point of the EasyAuth?

**The question:** Is this the default behavior for Azure EasyAuth and it does not support the described scenario or am I missing something?